# How to read in space-delimited information from a file in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, g++

In a text file I will have a line containing a series of numbers, with each number separated by a space.  How would I read each of these numbers and store all of them in an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
std::ifstream file("filename");
std::vector<int> array;
int number;
while(file >> number) {
    array.push_back(number);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just copy them from the stream to the array:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("filename");
    std::vector<int> array;

    std::copy(  std::istream_iterator<int>(file),
                std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                std::back_inserter(array));
}
```