# C++ Populate a vector of strings from a space-delimited text file

Tags: c++

I have a space delimited text file, from which I need to extract individual words to populate a `vector<string>`.

I've tried playing around with `strtok`, but I understand this is not working because `strtok` returns a `char pointer`. Any way to extract the words from the file, and fill the `string vector` with them? Thanks!

Comment: `ifstream fin(filename); string word; fin >> word;`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/1336150) might help you too...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read in space-delimited information from a file in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530738/how-to-read-in-space-delimited-information-from-a-file-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are "fancier" ways, but in my opinion the following's most understandable (and useful as a basis for variations) for beginners:

```
if (std::ifstream input(filename))
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;
    while (input >> word)
        words.push_back(word);
}
```

Comment: Just in case you're curious what's meant by fancier, `std::vector<std::string> vec ((std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in)), std::istream_iterator<std::string>());`, where `in` is the `ifstream` object.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using an `ifstream` to read the file.

Then you can use the `>> operator` to move the next word into the `string`.