# Unable to tokenize a string and pass to a vector <string>

Tags: c++, string, vector, cgi, strtok

I am experimenting with CGI in C++. I know that there are libraries which handle basic stuff, but in order to know whats going on under the hood i have been trying to parse the stdin using string datatype ---> tokenize using '= and &' then push_back into a vector. at the latter step, i am receiving segmentation fault. given below is the program where i am using cin>> to obtain user input and so on ..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    vector <string> stuff(0);
    vector<string>::iterator it;
    char* bufferchar;
    string buffer;


    char str[size];
    cout<<"Content-type: text/html\n\n"
      <<"<html>"
      <<"<head>"
      <<"<title>CGI SCRIPT</title>"
      <<"</head>"
      <<"<body>"
    fgets(str,20,stdin);      //20 is expect size of content from html form
    puts(str);

    cout<<"<p>Now to break this guy apart";
    int x=0;
    bufferchar = strtok(str,"&=");
    buffer+=bufferchar;
    stuff.push_back(buffer);
    while(bufferchar!=NULL){
      cout<<bufferchar<<'\n'<<'\n';
      bufferchar=strtok(NULL,"&=");
      buffer+=bufferchar;
      stuff.push_back(buffer);
      }
    cout<<"<br>ok does the vector iterate ?";
    for (it=stuff.begin();it!=stuff.end();++it){
      cout<<*it;
      cout<<"<br> ok man, next <br><br>";
    }
    cout<<"</body>";
    cout<<"</html>";
}
```

Comment: Use a string instead of a char*,char arrays and strtok. The string library has algorithms which would make your life a lot easier. You are using string for vectors, use for the char parts also.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Populate a vector of strings from a space-delimited text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166136/c-populate-a-vector-of-strings-from-a-space-delimited-text-file)